# Get most common value from DB

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table which contains thousands of rows. Columns include `user_id` and `city`

I am wanting to echo/print the most common `city` for a 'user_id' (user_id is a value on my page)

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Might be `COUNT`, `GROUP BY` & `LIMIT` could help.

Comment: Can't get you what you really want to do over here

Comment: @b0s3 - could you give me an example?

Comment: Read about them and you will have your answer.

Comment: @b0s3 -  I have tried `SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS city FROM user_logins WHERE user_id='$user' GROUP BY column ORDER BY city DESC LIMIT 1` with no luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(city) AS countcity FROM user_logins 
GROUP BY city ORDER BY countcity DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How do it manage the `for a 'user_id'` part of the question? (protip: it actually doesn't)